# Ao publicar o projeto no IIS não aparece script e css, o que pode ser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Ao publicar o projeto no servidor e configurar o **iis** ele não reconhece o css e script, ele não da erro, encontra o endereço mais não carrega o código css e js.

Verifiquei no diretório do publish no servidor, eu abro o arquivo no notepad e o código está la, mais ele não interpreta.

Se alguem tiver alguma ideia que possa ajudar, agradeço. Pois como se ver na imagem, tenho um monte de projeto publicado sem erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: é uma página html ou aspx?

Comment: asp.net, mas o css e Js que nao sao interpretados

Comment: pq paginas aspx podem dar problema com os paths dos recursos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alterei algumas tag do WebConfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Para obter mais informações sobre como configurar seu aplicativo ASP.NET, visite
   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <!-- <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />-->
    <sessionState timeout="300" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="180" />
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" fileEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- conexoes -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.6.0" newVersion="5.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DevExtreme.AspNet.Data" publicKeyToken="982f5dab1439d0f7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.5.0" newVersion="1.4.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <!-- <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      -->
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="AtendeClienteServiceSoapBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="AtendeClienteServiceSoapBinding1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AtendeClienteServiceSoapBinding" contract="WsCorreio.AtendeCliente" name="AtendeClientePort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: D056626B-E08D-4D5E-BF61-C38B50CDCE0C-->
```

Comment: Olá! O que exatamente foi a solução, quais linhas foram alteradas! Estou tendo o mesmo problema.